# Is "divisible by 15" the same as "divisible by 5 and divisible by 3"?

Tags: divisibility

Is stating that a number $x$ is divisible by 15 the same as stating that $x$ is divisible by 5 **and** $x$ is divisible by 3?

Comment: The two assertions are *equivalent*.

Comment: may be worth noting for somebody who might be new to this, that it happens to work in both directions here, because 3 and 5 are co-prime. i.e. if you ask the same question for a different example you may not get the converse implication.

Comment: If you want to figure out the general facts at work here, you could read [this Keith Conrad handout](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/divgcd.pdf).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, if a number $n$ is divisible by $15$, this means $n=15k$ for some integer $k$. So $n=5(3k)=3(5k)$, so it is also divisible by $3$ and $5$.

Conversely, if $n$ is divisible by $3$ and $5$, it is a simple lemma that it is divisible by the least common multiple of $3$ and $5$. Since $3$ and $5$ are coprime, their lcm is just $15$.

Comment: I feel that this answer is incomplete.  It does not prove that x|n and y|n implies that lcm(x,y)|n; it just claims it's "a simple lemma".  A better answer would show why this is true.

Comment: Suppose there's a number n such that x|n and y|n, but lcm(x,y) does not divide n.  Then write m = lcm(x,y) and n = pm+q, where 0 < q < m and p is an integer.  Then x and y must both divide q, so m is not the lcm of x and y - contradiction.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. $15|n \implies 3*5|n \implies 3|n \text{ and } 5|n$. Conversely, $3|n \text{ and } 5|n \implies 15|n$. This is because if $x|n$ and $y|n$, then $\text{lcm}(x,y)|n$ where $\text{lcm}(xy)$ is the smallest number that is divisible by both $x$ and $y$. In this case, $x=3$ and $y=5$, so $\text{lcm}(3,5) = 15$, therefore $15|n$.

(Note: $a|b$, read as "$a$ divides $b$", means that $b$ is divisible by $a$.)

Comment: You should also prove the other direction as Dedede has done below.

Comment: @BenjaminLim: Good point. Editing that in now.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman: You seem to have done nothing except write the OP's question as an assertion using mathematical language.  A proof or justification as to _why_ this works would be helpful.

Comment: I don't know enough math to pick the "most correct" answer. @El'endiaStarman answered first, I understood it, and it looked good to me! Dedede's has more upvotes though, so I went with that one.

Comment: @JavaMan: At this point, is there a reason I shouldn't just delete my answer? Dedede has already answered it perfectly.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman: Whether you delete it or not is up to you.  It seems that the post has been fixed.